# mobile connected to PC using usb cord

Tags: android, mobile

I am still learning android and I want to know if it is possible to connect my mobile phone while I am developing my application for android, and does running the AVD can also update 
the installed apk in my mobile phone Example if i have updated code then i will run the 
AVD in eclipse does the installed application in my mobile phone also will be updated if i 
am connected to my PC.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, you want to connect your phone to the PC and use it to debug / test your application.

Yes , it is possible and recommendable to test on real devices.

If you connect it and it is not recognized, you probably need to find the correct drivers for your phone model to be recognized.

Comment: hi where could i set this android:debuggable ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're looking for : http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html#RunningOnDeviceEclipse

Check running on device section

Comment: by the way I right click my project then run as->android application,does this will automatically installed apk to my mobile phone device?

Comment: Okay my mobile is now connected,but when i follow this instruction "Once set up and your device is connected via USB, install your application on the device by selecting Run > Run (or Run > Debug) from the Eclipse menu bar."..when i disconnect my mobile then i search it to my device my application is not installed

Comment: Hello @mathiascolebar . Well I haven't tried to install my projects on my device before because I'm afraid doing it many times might cause performance problems . You should do like plugging your device then hit run and wait until it opens . I think you are plugging off your device before the uploading/installing is completed so it's better to keep your device plugged .After you finish checking your application you can plug it off . Note : May I know why you don't want to use AVD ? It's better from my opinion .

Comment: also forgot to mention if you want to install your application manually on your phone then you can go to your workspace ->project file->bin and you will find your project's apk there , then copy it to your phone and browse it via file manager on your device then install it .

Comment: Hi,Thank you I just want to try on my device...so you mean if ever i have updated my application I am going to uninstall the application in my device then copy the new one in the workspace ->project file->bin  and install it again to my device?

Comment: Well it depends . Have you tried running in Eclipse and see if it will last after you unplug your device ? if not then I suggest you to code your application and do tests on AVD and when you're done copy it from project file to your device and install it ..